# IE edge browser png not showing properly, but showing fine in mozilla browser and chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using this image attribute but not showing exactly in IE edge browser. Please help me.

```
<img src="oneteam/custom/img/widget/checkbox-empty.png" style="width:21px; height:21px;cursor:pointer;">
```

[Click here for Firefox UI, its showing fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDsOp.png)

[Click here for IE browser UI, Checkbox border is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxFFw.png)

Comment: can you post jsfiddle link for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `border:none;` or `outline:none;` may be it will work.